# Adding onto an existing ColdFusion 2016 ORM application

Tags: orm, coldfusion, foreign-keys, mariadb, coldfusion-2016

I am working on adding to a ColdFusion 2016 application with ORM.  The application pulls up and doesn't give any type of errors prior to adding the second table code (`TableTwo`). As soon as the second table code is added, it gives an error saying:

> Can't create table `XXXXX`.`YYYYY` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint
>   is incorrectly formed")

Where `XXXXX` is the name of the application as a whole - not `TableOne`, `TableTwo` or `BaseTable`.

Are there any ideas as to what is causing the application to give such an error?

If I delete all references to `TableTwo` and reload ORM, the application will pull up again.  `TableOne` and `TableTwo` need to join to the `BaseTable`, but will not join to each other.

Below is an example of how the code is currently formatted.

**TableOne.cfc**

```
component {

   property name="id" fieldType="id"  ormtype="int" type="numeric" generator="native";
   property name="baseTableID" ormtype="int" type="numeric" insert="false" update="false";

   //relations
   property name"baseTable" fieldType="one-to-one" cfc="BaseTable" fkcolumn="baseTableID" joincolumn="id" notnull="true"  casecade="save-update";

}
```

**BaseTable.cfc**

```
component {

   property name="id" fieldType="id" ormtype="int" type="numeric" generator="native";

   //relations
   property name="TableOne" fieldtype="one-to-one" cfc="TableOne"  mappedby="baseTable" cascade="all-delete-orphan";

   --Attempting to add a second one
   property name="TableTwo" fieldtype="one-to-one" cfc="TableTwo"  mappedby="baseTable" cascade="all-delete-orphan";

}
```

**TableTwo.cfc**

```
component {

   property name="id" fieldType="id"  ormtype="int" type="numeric" generator="native";
   property name="baseTableID" ormtype="int" type="numeric" insert="false" update="false";

   //relations
   property name"BaseTable" fieldType="one-to-one" cfc="BaseTable" fkcolumn="baseTableID" joincolumn="id" notnull="true"  casecade="save-update";

}
```

Comment: You have a typo in the `property` attribute of the BaseTable within the TableOne.cfc and TableTwo.cfc files.  Instead of `cascade` you have `casecade`. Is that actually in your code or just here on stackoverflow?